# Can SRV DNS record be used to allow Mincraft to connect to a non-default port without specifying the port number?

Tags: dns, port-number, srv-records

I own a Minecraft Server with a non standard port and i want the user to connect without port. So i tried setting up an A and a SRV Record for my Domain.

A Record:

- join.domainName.xyz
- MineCraftServerIP

SRV Record:

- _minecraft._tcp.join.domainName.xyz
- Priority:0
- Weight:5
- minecraftServerPort
- join.domainName.xyz

if i run nslookup -q=SRV _minecraft._tcp.join.domainName.xyz i get

```
priority = 0
weight = 5
port = minecraftServerPort
svr hostname = join
```

but on Minecraft i get "Cant resolve Hostname", if i add the minecraftServerPort behind join.domainName.xyz, it is working, i thought SRV Record can be used to hide the port?

Comment: Have you waited more than 24 hours for the DNS changes to take place? since its not instant.

Comment: Also, confirm that your A record is `join` and not `join.example.com` because adding the later will not work, most DNS providers will prevent adding that record.

Comment: i Switched NameServers and my Domain to cloudflare and entered there the informations for A and SRV and now it is working as it should, i guess the One i was before was just buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After swiching to Cloudflare and making the same settings there, everything works fine now.

Comment: Andrew what do you mean? O.O